# Set individual input element to ng-pristine

Tags: angularjs

I know there is a $setPristine() function for the form element, is there an equivalent if I want single to set to ng-pristine single element tags like `<input>`?

Comment: Why am I downvoted for asking?

Comment: Don't know.  Question looks good to me.  When I downvote a question, I always add a comment explaining why I am downvoting as it helps the original poster understand what could be improved.  I'm not a great fan of anonymous downvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept of pristine applies to a form as a whole and not to individual elements.  A pristine form is one which has not yet been modified while a dirty form is one that has been changed.  There are no semantics of flagging a input element unrelated to a form as pristine and for input elements in a form, the pristine flag applies solely to the form.