# setPristine for a single input field

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use setPristine method for a single input field in my form. There are ways to do this for the entire form but i want to do this only to one input field in my form.How can i do this?

I tried it this way

```
$scope.merchantDetails.customer_id.$setPristine = true;
```

But did not work.

This is the input field i want to set it to pristine state on some function.

```
<input class="form-control" id="id_customer_id" name="customer_id" placeholder="Auto-generated if empty" title="" type="text" maxlength="8" ng-keydown="check();" ng-model="customer.customerId">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837258/set-individual-input-element-to-ng-pristine

Answer (score 4):

Probably you can try this.

```
$scope.form.customer_id.$setPristine(false);
```

Have a look into this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kUZt88nGCoEQpyNdMoLl?p=preview).It might work for u.