# Re-set all forms to pristine status from the bottom up

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

We have smDateTimePicker directive which is rather complex. This time picker control can be part of another directive and that directive can be placed into the form (or a tab). In that smDateTimePicker directive we have code resetting form to pristine status (and I added last 2 lines just now):

```js
DateTimePicker.prototype.setPristine = function () {
        if (this.form) {
            this.form.$setPristine();

            if (this.form.$$parentForm.$dirty) {
                this.form.$$parentForm.$setPristine();
            }
            if (this.form.$$parentForm.$$parentForm && this.form.$$parentForm.$$parentForm.$dirty) {
                this.form.$$parentForm.$$parentForm.$setPristine();
            }
        }
    };
```

I don't like that I need to use $$parentForm property and I need to use it twice for my particular case. Besides, what if I have deeper hierarchy? Is there a cleaner way to re-set all forms to pristine from the bottom up?

Comment: Setting pristine using the bottom up approach doesn't look right... This code looks way too fragile and could break at any instance. What you should do it to set pristine from the parent level. If at most, parent should be responsible for updating child behavior, not vice-versa.

Comment: I agree, but I'm not sure what to do in our situation for that complex directive. The directive has form property that refers to the form it's being used on. Unfortunately, somehow when we're changing datepicker value in code the very top form dirty status is being set. I don't think we have a control over that.

Comment: I think (not yet sure) this is what sets the very top form's dirty status: this.datetimepicker = this.element.find(".input-group").datetimepicker(this.OPTIONS);
                        this.datetimepicker.data("DateTimePicker").date(val);
                        input.val(val);

                        DateTimePicker.link.onDateTimePickerChange.call(this, this.ngModelController);
                        this.setPristine();

Comment: Ok. One way of doing this within the directive itself (rather a workaround) would be do this through a recursive loop - just like you would manipulate a tree structure where you would keep looking for the parent, grand parent, great grand parent etc in a recursive manner. This would enable your code being agnostic on the hierarchy of forms and would be much cleaner + less lines of code. I could write that piece of code as a sample.

Comment: BTW, this is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837258/set-individual-input-element-to-ng-pristine I wish there will be something inside the angular (may be second parameter inside $setPristine method) to force all parent elements as well

Comment: I re-wrote the above as recursive function and it works nicely. I do use $$parentForm which I don't like. If you can re-post your suggestion as an answer, I'll mark it so. Thanks.

Comment: I will post my answer today. A recursion seemed more sensible in this case and that's why I recommended it. Using $$parentForm is inevitable in this case and I don't see a major issue using that (though I understand your concern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you. You may have to do minor changes if needed:

```
DateTimePicker.prototype.setPristine = function () {
        if (this.form) {
            setPristineToForm(this.form);
        }
    };

    // Recursive method - goes up the hierarchy of forms
    var setPristineToForm = function (form) {
        if (form) {
            //Check if a parent form exists. If it does, set parent's pristine 
            var parentForm = this.form.$$parentForm;

            if (parentForm) {
                setPristineToForm(parentForm);
            }
            else { //No parent exist. Set pristine to current form if it is dirty.
                if (form.$dirty)
                    form.$setPristine();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Yes, that's along the same lines I implemented yesterday. Works quite nicely.